# Check is web app in fullscreen

Tags: html, ios, safari, meta-tags, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm using meta tag to put web app in full screen on iPad

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Is there a way so I can check is app in full screen ?

Main reason for this is to increase wrapper height if app is in full screen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Javascript to determine that on iOS devices.

```
if(!!window.navigator.standalone){
  //browser
}else{
  //full screen
}
```

Using that function will determine the current state and execute the corresponding code.